# Retry mechanism - 3rd party provider

Tags: sql, apache-kafka, 3rd-party

I have the scenario below and what I want to do is to build a retry mechanism to retrieve a status. 
So, what we have is a payment system and we want to call a 3rd party provided periodically in order to retrieve the payment status. 
More specifically, we want to do it exponentially, 1st time after 1s, 2nd time after 2s, 3rd time after 4s, etc.

I am thinking of a naive solution using SQL table in order to store every different action or using a message broker like Kafka as a Queue.

What do you think that is a good solution on that?

Answer (score -1):

I've already been confronted with this but had a work around that didn't make me do a retry system with exponential timeout limit.

Here:[npm retry module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/retry)

I propose you do another service with low priority to do the request and write over your database.
This way you can monitor better the start, timeout, restart and pause time to request the data you need and don't compromise the main app.

I know it isn't the tech your using but can help you reach a simple solution seeing how others do.

Hope it helped!